# Using XML Functions(XMLAGG) in RPGLE

Tags: xml, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a table(TableA) from which I am creating a single XML from 2 of its fields (Fld1 and Fld2)

```
 select  
   XMLSERIALIZE(
     XMLAGG(
       XmlElement(Name "Tag", 
       XmlElement(Name "PARTNUMBER",  RTrim(Fld1)), 
       XmlElement(Name "PART_DESCRIPTION", RTrim(Fld2)))
     )
  AS varchar(2000)  )  
   From TableA
```

The Output is as below:

```
<Tag><PARTNUMBER>401791</PARTNUMBER><PART_DESCRIPTION>ECM-NO START,ME17</PART_DESCRIPTION></Tag><Tag><PARTNUMBER>401792</PARTNUMBER><PART_DESCRIPTION>CALIBRATION-111,IND,18,NA</PART_DESCRIPTION></Tag>
```

Now my requirement is that the  should only come once. It should be binding the entire XML and not for each row.

The required Output should be as below:

```
 <Tag><PARTNUMBER>401791</PARTNUMBER><PART_DESCRIPTION>ECM-NO> START,ME17</PART_DESCRIPTION><PARTNUMBER>401792</PARTNUMBER><PART_DESCRIPTION>CALIBRATION-111,IND,18,NA</PART_DESCRIPTION></Tag>
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the output you are requesting, this should do the trick...

```
    SELECT 
        XMLELEMENT(NAME "TAG",
            XMLAGG(
                XMLFOREST(RTRIM(Fld1) AS "PARTNUMBER",
                          RTRIM(Fld2) AS "PART_DESCRIPTION"
                )
            )
        )

        AS XML_EXAMPLE 
     FROM TableA
```

Now after you have generated that, you can throw this inside of another select statement and use XMLSERIALIZE to add in whatever you need at the beginning.

Also, here is the IBM documentation on the three XML functions used above.

XMLELEMENT: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscaxmlelem.htm

XMLAGG: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcolxmlagg.htm

XMLFOREST: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscaxmlforest.htm

Comment: Good answer but wrong docs, the OP's user name and tags used indicate he is using Db2 for IBM i... [Db2 for i docs for XMLFOREST](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscaxmlforest.htm)

Comment: Thanks JRR.. That worked like a Charm.. Should have posted the question here before itself so that I could have saved some Hours.. Thanks a lot